# Android Share to G+ is missing location field

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

The location field no longer appears in the share to G+ dialog on Android. This is the code I'm using:

```
Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this.getActivity())
        .setType("text/plain")
        .setText("Test")
        .getIntent();
startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
```

Previously, in the share dialog, you could add the location (similar to the "Write" dialog in the G+ app). With a recent update to play services, that location field is no longer there.

Am I missing something?

[This is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsBWt.png) of the current share dialog.

And [this is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7ow7.png) of the write dialog in the G+ app.

Answer (score 0):

The sharing actually moved from the Google+ app to Google Play Services, and they are slightly different sharing experiences - for example the new contacts first sharing is only in the Google Play services sharebox. If its a feature you're keen on, probably the best bet is to file a request in the Platform issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list